# Can I rebind the camera drag to another mouse button in Starcraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Starcraft II, when you hold the third mouse button and move the mouse you drag your camera.

But there are two drawbacks to this:

1. It requires me to remove one of my fingers of one of the main buttons.
2. The button results in an annoying *click* sound, which is not useful for room mates and casting.

I've figured out that the two buttons at the side of my mouse aren't used for anything.

**So, how do I bind the drag action to one of these side buttons?**

This is subject to two things:

1. It should not violate the terms of agreement, so I guess third-party software is not allowed.
2. This buttons have to retain their original functionality in other applications, e.g. browser.

Comment: My understanding is the upcoming patch will be released within the next week and it most likely will allow you to do that, but it's impossible to be sure without trying it myself. What mouse do you have? Most good brands bundle software that would allow you to reassign the buttons.

Comment: Some local brand mouse that just works Plug-and-Play over Bluetooth, it has two side buttons which are recognized as the fourth and fifth button in a lot of games so it should in theory be possible to be able to do this in StarCraft II. They are indeed revamping the hotkey settings, but I wonder if this would include the mouse settings.

Comment: Sorry, but why do you need to change you camera at all?

Comment: Because of the two drawbacks? Dragging works much better and is less annoying when playing/casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can. Open the Hokeys page from the Menu, open the Global tab, expand the Camera node and it should be obvious how to change the key or add an alternate key after clicking on the Drag Scroll setting.

Comment: The patch has not been released yet in Europe, will confirm this later.

Answer (score 2):

Get Autohotkey
http://www.autohotkey.com/download/

If you think this is violating the TOS read http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewpost.php?post_id=7436604

I use Autohotkey to remap some keys, so you shouldn't get banned for this.

Here is a script that will do what you ask. You may need to change XButton1 to XButton2

```
#SingleInstance force
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.

#IfWinActive ahk_class StarCraft II

XButton1::MButton
```

Comment: +1 but going to wait for the patch to see if StarCraft II will allow me to change it there, I'm using XMouse in the mean-time.